# Destination tag in ripple

Tags: ripple

how use destination tag in remote in ripple when we make a payment?I tried with destination_tag and dtag in remote block.

Comment: What do you mean by "in remote"? What software exactly are you talking to? The usual way is to include a "DestinationTag" entry in the [payment transaction](https://developers.ripple.com/payment.html).